# How to subtract time in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

New to Rails, so please bear with me. I have a :time type column in db for the field start_time. Now, I have to check whether the start_time is greater or not by 5 hours from the current_time.

When I retrieve the **start_time** in rails console, it gives me: (The date never changes in this only the time)

```
2000-01-01 10:00:00 +0000
```

And the current time i.e **Time.now**

```
Sun, 23 Jul 2017 20:58:23 IST +05:30
```

I have stored both the values in variables, like so,

```
a = start_time     #2000-01-01 10:00:00 +0000
b = Time.zone.now  #Sun, 23 Jul 2017 20:58:23 IST +05:30
```

Now, what I want is something like below:

```
if ((a - b) > 5 hours)
  #do something
end
```

I am not able to figure out how to do it. I don't care about the date, I just need the time difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c = ((b - a) / 1.hour).round.modulo(24)
if c > 5
  # do something
end
```

- a and b as your sample above
- ((b - a) / 1.hour).round this will result hour difference between 2 dates and then round it to ignore minutes
- module(24) = will output just hour difference
- if 1.hour not working you can replace it with c = ((b - a) / 3600)

Answer (score 1):

Try convert the UTC time to the same time zone:

```
a = start_time     #2000-01-01 10:00:00 +0000
b = Time.zone.now  #Sun, 23 Jul 2017 20:58:23 IST +05:30
same_time_kind = b.to_date
```

then compare:

```
if ((a - b) > 5.hours)
  #do something
end
```

Comment: It doesn't work as by yours method I only get date and as I have mentioned in the question. I don't care about date. I just need the difference between time. Because since date is different for the start_time and current_time it's creating problem

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to convert Time to Integer:

```
a = start_time.to_i
b = Time.zone.now.to_i

if ((a - b) > 5.hours.to_i)
  #do something
end
```